# MongoDB Aggregation simple Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

I've this sample MongoDB data:

```
{"FirstName": "Bruce", "LastName": "Wayne", 
"Email": "bwayne@Wayneenterprises.com"}
{"FirstName": "Lucius", "LastName": "Fox", 
"Email": "lfox@Wayneenterprises.com"}
{"FirstName": "Dick", "LastName": "Grayson", 
"Email": "dgrayson@Wayneenterprises.com"}
```

and what I'm trying to get and find the count of all documents

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
   db.col.aggregate([  {$match:{  "Bed Grade":4}}  , {  $group: {_id:{h:"$Hospital_code" ,d:"$Department" } , cnt:{$sum:1}} }  , {$match:{cnt:{$gt:5}}}  ])
```

Comment: Thank you!, could I share another question?